# Create table out of two tables with no link between them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of IDs and a list of metrics. There is no link between them. I want to join them in a table each ID has all metrics. I show the desired result below:
[image]

I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cross join as follows:

```
select id, metrics
from table1 cross join table2
```